# How to enter and solve this equation in finite fields?

Tags: equation-solving, finite-fields

Is there a way in Mathematica 9 to enter and solve the following equation

$p(x) = r^x$

where $p(x)$ is a polynomial whose coefficients are drawn from a finite field, and $r$ is a primitive root of the field modulus ?

EDIT

As an example, how to solve

$x^3 + x^5 == 3^x$ mod 7

Comment: There is the `Modulus` option in `Solve` however my experience is that it isn't perfect.

Comment: @Artes, thank you. I have edited my question adding an example equation I would like to solve. Forgive me, if my knowledge was better, I would not ask ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the question is that exponential functions such as `b^x` are not well-defined functions modulo `m`, even when `m` is prime.  In general, when the base `b` is relatively prime to `m`, the period of `b^x` divides `EulerPhi[m]`.

The same problem of defining `b^x` holds when `b` and `x` belong to a field of order `λ^n`.  I only know of the exponential being defined for `x` an integer, which induces a function on the integers modulo `λ-1` in the case of a finite field of characteristic `λ`.

Example:

```
λ = 71;
Pick[Range[λ], Mod[x^3 + x^5 - 3^x, λ] /. {x -> Range[λ]}, 0]
Pick[Range[λ], Mod[x^3 + x^5 - 3^x, λ] /. {x -> 3 λ + Range[λ]}, 0]

(* {54} *)
(* {34} *)
```

Conclusion: If `x` is to be an element of a finite field, then the equation is undefined.

If, however, `x` is merely to be chosen from the set of integers `{1, .., λ}`, then the following will work.

```
λ = 71; (* changing the prime from 7 to 71 *)
Pick[Range[λ], Table[Mod[x^3 + x^5 - 3^x, λ], {x, λ}], 0]

(* {54} *)
```

If `x` is to be chosen from the set `{0, .., λ-1}`, then use the following instead.

```
Pick[Range[0, λ-1], Table[Mod[x^3 + x^5 - 3^x, λ], {x, 0, λ-1}], 0]
```

But it only makes a difference (for this example equation) for `λ = 3`.

Comment: I doubt there is anything significantly better than brute search (like this). Solve can handle such problems over R due to a sophisticated extension of polynomial rootfinding. Over finite fields I'm not aware of any such capability.

Comment: If the finite field $\mathbb{F}$ has a small number of elements, one can obtain the Lagrange interpolation polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $f(x_i) = r^{x_i}$ for all elements $x_i \in \mathbb{F}$. This polynomial is *identical* to $r^{x}$ because we are working on a finite field.  The problem is reduced to finding the roots of the polynomial $g = p - f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$.  A brute-force approach, trying every element in the field would work.  Another possibility would be to factor $g$ using Berlekamp's or Cantor–Zassenhaus's algorithms and read the roots off the factors.

Comment: However, both exhaustive search and the Berlekamp's and Cantor–Zassenhaus's algorithms require exponential time. I need to be sure that no polynomial time algorithm exists in order to apply this to the construction of a cryptographic protocol.